# How to communicate between directive (tree component) and any other controller or directive in AngularJS app?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

First of all, I have read so much info you all share about communication between controllers, that I'm now so confused about the BEST way to do it. I understand I should use service, but don't really know what it means from the examples you all wrote.

Here is my scenario: 
Left side of my page I have a side bar with a simple folder/files tree. I have used angular Tree Component and it works great for me: http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/

On the right side of the page, I have a view that is being changed by user navigation.
Each time user select any node on the tree, I want to be able to tell any right side page controller which node has been selected. Each selection on tree should notify any one who want to listen to that change.

I don't like the idea of using $rootScope and fire event from the service, Is that the only way?

Comment: That seems like the best way. It does exactly what you want to do. I don't see any use for a service if you're communicating using events. The directive has access to the $rootScope service directly, and the controllers has a $scope.

Comment: What's the nature of the communication you seek? If it is just to share data I would say that your best option is to use a Service, I don't like using $rootScope either.

Comment: if your right hand side directive $scope is child of controllers $scope, then you should $emit from current $scope, also you can use this pubsub library for angularjs which optimizes communication little bit, but the best way is a service.

Comment: What if you have two instance of the same directive?
The service has one instance, how you know which one of them you are applying?

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate how it can be done, I created some example code using a service to share data between Controllers and Directives:

```
app.factory('SharedService', function() {
  return {
    sharedObject: {
      value: ''
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1VdKJP2tpvqqJL1LF6m?p=preview

Hope that helps

Comment: 10x! It really helps to understand.

Comment: What if you have the same directive but twice, like the tree directive, but you have two tree. The service is singleton, so how can you tell in service which directive he should update. What can be done in this scenario?

Comment: In that case your directive has a `dependency`, so one way to solve it is to pass the value it should watch by an attribute, please take a look at the plunkr, I just updated it with an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1VdKJP2tpvqqJL1LF6m?p=preview

Comment: Did that help at all?