# Ui-router nested views with changing ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-class

I have a website setup like below.  When that `Button C` clicked it has to change `myClass` value.

Class that index.html has: `myClass = "container gnc1"`

Wanted value that when `Button C` clicked: `myClass = "container"`

```
<body ui-view="viewA">  //firtsCtrl
    <div ng-class="myClass">
    <div ui-view="viewC">
    <div ui-view="viewB">

        <a ui-sref="B">Button B</a> //Loads the B.html to where viewB is. secondCtrl


        <a ui-sref="C" ng-click="removeClass()">Button C</a> //Loads the C.html where viewC is. thirdCtrl


 </div>

 </div>
```

Here is my code:

firstCtrl:

```
.controller('indexCtrl', function($scope, MY) {
        $scope.myClass = ["container","gnc1"];
        $scope.removeClass = function() {
        $scope.myClass.splice(1, 2);
}
})
```

But this didn't work. When I click `Button C` "myClass" value getting empty and div had no class in it.

Comment: how about trying with $scope.myClass=$scope.myClass[0]; inside the remove class function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more `angular`ish way to do this is to bind your changing class with a `$scope` variable, so you can change it from your controller, also if you need to share data between your controllers you should use a `service`, see how to do this here: [How to communicate between directive (tree component) and any other controller or directive in AngularJS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349845/how-to-communicate-between-directive-tree-component-and-any-other-controller-o/25354097#25354097)

```
<div ng-class="{'gnc1': yourVariable}" class="container">
    <div ui-view="viewC">
    <div ui-view="viewB">
        <a ui-sref="B">Button B</a>
        <a ui-sref="C" ng-click="removeClass()">Button C</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And on your controller:

```
.controller('indexCtrl', function($scope, MY) {
        $scope.yourVariable = true;
        $scope.removeClass = function() {
            $scope.yourVariable = false;
        }
})
```